Use full width for SelectButton and ButtonGroup PrimeVue components
I have the following page in a Vue 3 application and on smaller screens I want the SelectButton and ButtonGroup components to use full width. The parent components use full widths, yet the inner buttons would need to stretch out to use all available space evenly. I have tried overriding the slots, but just ended up breaking the whole styling. I would also lke to have the SelectButton component to be raised too.
I use PrimeVue V3 with PrimeFlex
<template>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="flex flex-column md:flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center mb-5">
                <SelectButton v-model="ptSelected" :options="ptSelectOptions" optionLabel="name" optionValue="value"
                    class="w-full md:w-30rem mb-3 md:mb-0">
                </SelectButton>

                <ButtonGroup class="w-full md:w-30rem mb-3 md:mb-0">
                    <Button raised icon="pi pi-chevron-left"></Button>
                    <Button raised label="Today"></Button>
                    <Button label="Title" raised></Button>
                    <Button raised icon="pi pi-chevron-right"></Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import SelectButton from 'primevue/selectbutton';
import ButtonGroup from 'primevue/buttongroup';
import Button from 'primevue/button';

const ptSelected = ref("");

const ptSelectOptions = computed(() => [
    { name: '1', value: 'allPractitioner' },
    { name: '2', value: 'onlyWorking' },
    { name: '3', value: 'selected' }
]);
</script>

<style scoped></style>

On large screen:

On small screen (md or smaller), each item should be placed in separate rows and should use full width. As for the ButtonGroup component, chevrons should stay small but the other two buttons should use up all the space


Please, specify how the layout is intended to look like exactly. An image would help

@EstusFlask Thank you and I have uploaded the images
